Permutation and Combinations ways of arrangement(at Least)
There are 5 boys and 4 girls now in how many ways can committee of 4 people be formed with at least 2 boys
ChatGPT said:
ChatGPT
To determine the number of ways to form a committee of 4 people with at least 2 boys, we can break this problem into cases based on the number of boys in the committee:
Total Boys in the Committee
Case 1: 2 boys and 2 girls
Case 2: 3 boys and 1 girl
Case 3: 4 boys and 0 girls
Now, let's compute the combinations for each case:
Case 1: 2 boys and 2 girls
Total ways for this case: 10×6 = 60
Case 2: 3 boys and 1 girl
Total ways for this case: 10×4=40 10 x 4 = 40
Case 3: 4 boys and 0 girls
Total ways for this case: 5×1= 5
Total Number of Ways
Adding all the cases together, the total number of ways to form the committee is:
60+40+5=10560 + 40 + 5 = 10560+40+5=105
But, I think this should also be possible
Since we have to select at least 2 boys, so the number of ways we can do that is 5C2 = 10 and now the remaining number of students is 7 and now we can also use 7C2 = 21 for the next group and combine them to get 210,
I am stuck at where the mistake lies in the solution can anyone help??

You are overcounting.  Given the committee, you can't tell which $2$ boys were chosen initially and which were chosen later, so you multiply count those committees with $3$ or $4$ boys.

May be worth saying:  I think the fact that the incorrect method leads to twice the correct answer is purely a coincidence.  It arises from the fact that you count the $3-$boy committees three times each, when you mean to count it only once (giving you $2\times 40=80$ in covercounting) and you count the $4-$ boy committees $\binom 42=6$ times when, again, you meant to only count it once (giving you $5\times 5=25$ in overcounting).  And $80+25=105$ which happens to be the correct value.

Easier is simply $$\binom{9}{4} - \left[ ~\binom{5}{0} ~\binom{4}{4} ~\right] - \left[ ~\binom{5}{1} ~\binom{4}{3} ~\right].$$

@user2661923 Yep I also think this process is quite easy to understand and I have also found the flaw in my method thanks to comment from lulu

@lulu Thanks I got it now
